# Expression of an endomorphism when restricted to the subspace generated by it on an element

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space (over $\mathbb C$ if need be) and $A \in End_\mathbb C(V)$ an endomorphism. Suppose for some $f \in V$, the space $W_f:= \langle f, Af, \ldots, A^i f, \ldots \rangle$ is finite dimensional. Then it's easy to see that for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\{ f, Af, \ldots, A^n f \}$ is a basis in $W_f$.

My question is, is there anything we can say about the matrix of $A\vert_{W_f}$ with respect to this basis? Obviously it looks like:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & c_1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & c_2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & c_3 \\
\vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & c_n
\end{pmatrix}

but is there anything we can say about $c_i$?

Comment: When $f=0$ the basis would be $\{\}$. You could allow $n=-1$, rather than only $n\in\mathbb{N}$, to cover that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is contained in what you have written. Just take an arbitrary matrix like the one  you have written, and use it to define an endomorphism $A$ of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$.

Comment: If for example $c_i = 0$ for all $i=1, \ldots, n$, taking $f=(1,0,\ldots, 0)$ we have that $W_f$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional, so $A$ is not the matrix of the restriction to $W_f$ ot the endomorphism defined by $A$ on $\mathbb C^n$. So I don't understand why we can realize any matrix as the matrix of an endomorphism restricted to a finite dimensional $W_f$, which is what you claim, if I understand.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but taking the simplest example $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, and $f$ as you say, one gets that $W$ is two-dimensional,

Comment: The point being that your generic matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & c_1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 &c_2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 &c_3 \\
 & & & \ddots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1& c_n
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: BTW, the truly simplest example if $A = \begin{bmatrix}0\end{bmatrix}$, with $f = 1$.